# Why is my cat suddenly slapping me?

Tags: cats

I recently adopted a cat and she had adjusted very well to my home. We settled into a routine. She liked to hop onto my lap to snuggle / take a nap (and I’d let her and such) at least once a day, often more. She even did t by is on one day for several hours. She would also always want to know where I am in the house, and sleep In my bed. She loved when I would hold out my hand and let her rub her ears against it each way.

yesteday, I noticed she was less affectionate and seemed distant. She also seemed on edge and like she was getting tense to every little noise (it’s an older home, and also voices from outside can be heard in the living room). She seemed on-edge. After brushing her, I petted her one and then put out my arm for her to sniff & rub against like she normally does everyday multiple times a day and she slapped it. I’m not sure if I caught her off guard when I pet her before that, so I tried to disregard it. But when I got home later, she didn’t want to sit on my lap or cuddle or anything like normal. She also didn’t sleep wit me. She usually “meows” If I am in another area of the home for a while because she wonders where I am but she wasn’t doing that much yesterday and not today either. I noticed her sitting in random areas just Looking around and she seems angry or on edge.

I tried to give her some space this morning but she again didn’t sit on my lap when I woke up like she normally would’ve. She did not come to my room to wake me up either like normal (she was up but just didn’t come down). She was hanging out upstairs in the empty room which she doesn’t usually do. After a few hours I went to check on her and held out my hand to sniff which she did. The seater accidentally “shocked” her so that may have scare her. When she came downstairs, she started rubbing her face against the chairs which is usually when I brush her and let her rub her chin & ears against my hand. I held out my hand and she then slapped me again.

normally when I am on the couch she will jump up and sit on or with me but she’s sitting at the other end by the window. This is so odd and I am worried she hates me now. I appreciate any thoughts or advice you have!!!

Comment: when a cat changes behaviour for unknown reasons you should take him/her to the vet as it might be a sign your cat is in pain or might have medical problems,a cat might slap you for many different reasons most often because you do something the cat do not like.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot answer why she slapped you, simply because we cannot know what's going on in her head.

However, the behavior change could be a warning sign. You should monitor her during the next days:

- Does she hide away for long times?
- Does she become lethargic, less active or sit in a cowering posture most of the time?
- Does she start to pant or breathe heavily without physical exertion?
- Does she eat, drink, urinate or defecate less than usual or does she start drooling more than usual?
- Does she urinate or defecate outside the litter box?

All of the above behaviors could be signs that she's unwell and you should get her checked by a vet ASAP if you observe any of them. She might be in pain (like arthritis or kidney stones), have a reaction to some substance like paint or a cleaning product or she might have found some old rat poison or the like.

If there are no additional warning signs, she might simply be in a bad mood or have a mild infection. Cats can get a cold or stomach flue as well. Keep an eye on her and don't hesitate to call a local vet for some advice.